Why do we say that React's synthetic events solve cross-browser compatibility?
When I write:
btn.addEventListener("click", someFunction);

It runs without any issues in all browsers. So, I'm confused about why React's synthetic events are needed to address cross-browser compatibility when this event handler already works in all browsers. Moreover, if it's about supporting older browsers, isn't Babel.js responsible for resolving this? After all, Babel.js is involved in React projects. Can you help clarify this for me??

Babel is about older versions of JavaScript and has nothing to do with browser APIs.


It runs without any issues in all browsers

There are subtle differences about the event object that will be passed into someFunction, based on what browser you're using. For example, if you want to stop an event from bubbling, do you do so with event.stopPropagation() or event.cancelBubble()? .stopPropagation is the modern standard, but some older browsers won't have it. The synthetic event always has a .stopPropagation function, and will delegate to .cancelBubble if necessary.
If you'd like to see the other differences which SyntheticEvents handle, you can see the source code here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/events/SyntheticEvent.js

Moreover, if it's about supporting older browsers, isn't Babel.js responsible for resolving this?

Babel can rewrite your code to use older javascript syntax, but it won't rewrite your code to call .cancelBubble instead of .stopPropagation.
